# Do i need to create activity for each page in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I'm creating an android app In which there will be around 20-25 screens. If I create an activity for each screen it won't be feasible. What should I do? Should I create an activity for each page or not. If not then what's the other option?

Comment: You can use multiple fragments.

Comment: You can create _BaseActivity_ and extends other activities with _BaseActivity_. If you are comfortable with fragments then you can use that  in which you need to handle back stack of fragments.

Comment: Each page display the same kind of data?

Comment: It's like social media app. @SanjayBhalani

Comment: Can you please explain further. I don't get things you said about fragment. @Piyush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to, you can do this using fragments, using a single activity

[here](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-multiple-fragments-in-one-activity-example/) is a complete example of a single activity.

**Update**

A fragment is a tool that you can replace with activity. Actually, there are many reasons why one should use fragment over the activity.

- Reusability, which means you can create inflate one layout and easily add or remove from arguably any screen
- Split screen feature is easy to implement with the fragment
- *Whatever activity can do fragment also can do*
- It is lightweight with a back stack option

and many others, even nowadays it is very trendy to build an Android Application with single activity with multiple fragments, even `JetPack` suggests a library called `Navigation Component` to reduce the overhead to build single activity application

Comment: I am not asking about different device screen but i am asking about different pages. Should i need to create activity for all the pages? I want to create social media app using firebase.

Comment: Does fragment is more convenient than activity?

Comment: I have updated my answer, have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use fragments:

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in a FragmentActivity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

You can find how to create a fragment using [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating) link.